# Restarting the game after game over

Tags: java, keylistener

in the game that I made I have an game over screen that shows your score, now I want to make the game restart if you press space so that you dn't need to close the program and open it again to play it again. The problem isn't how to make the game restart when you press space but to acctualy make it restart. I have tried this code:

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && papi.isAlive() != true){ 
            remove(papi);
            papi.setSize(600,600);
            add(papi);
            setVisible(true);
            repaint();
        }
```

Why don't it work? I have tried to make an exact copy of the class that hods the game code and then add that instead of the same class and that works. Unfortunately I can't do that all the time because I need it to be able to be restarted as many times as the layer want and not only one time.

This is the code that starts the game:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    private PAPITest papi;
    private JPanel panel;
    private boolean inMenu = true;
    private ImageIcon ii;
    private Image image;

    public Game(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        requestFocus();
        ii = new ImageIcon("Ball Jump.png");
        image = ii.getImage();
        papi = new PAPITest();
        panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(inMenu == true){
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
            g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        requestFocusInWindow();
        requestFocus();
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == e.VK_SPACE && inMenu == true){
            inMenu = false;
            remove(panel);
            papi.setSize(600,600);
            papi.setAlive(true);
            add(papi);            
            setVisible(true); 
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && papi.isAlive() != true){ 
            remove(papi);
            papi.setSize(600,600);
            add(papi);
            setVisible(true);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Game();
    }
}
```

and this is the code for the game:
    package Game;

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.vecmath.*;

public class PAPITest extends Applet implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    private TransformGroup objTrans,objTrans2, objTrans3, objTrans4, objTrans5, objTrans6, objTrans7;
    private Transform3D trans = new Transform3D();
    private BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot2 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot3 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot4 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot5 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot6 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot7 = new BranchGroup();
    private SimpleUniverse u;
    private Canvas3D c;
    private BranchGroup scene, scene2, scene3, scene4, scene5, scene6, scene7;
    private Sphere sphere, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4, sphere5, sphere6, sphere7;
    private float height = 0.0f, sign = 1.0f, xloc = 0.0f;
    private float height2 = 0.0f, sign2 = -1.0f;
    private float rightX, right, rightDx, leftX, left, leftDx, rightX2, leftX2;
    private boolean isAlive = true;
    private JLabel scoreLabel;
    private int score = -400;
    private Timer timer;
    public int sumScore;


    public boolean isAlive(){
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean isAlive){
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(){
        Color3f ambientColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.6f,0.0f,0.0f);
        Color3f emissiveColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        Color3f diffuseColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.8f,0.0f,0.4f);
        Color3f specularColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.3f,0.0f,0.0f);
        float shininessRSphere = 20.0f;
        Appearance redSphereApp = new Appearance();
        redSphereApp.setMaterial(new Material(ambientColourRSphere,emissiveColourRSphere,
                             diffuseColourRSphere,specularColourRSphere,shininessRSphere));
        objRoot.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
        sphere = new Sphere(0.15f,redSphereApp);
        objTrans = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans.addChild(sphere);
        objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere
                (new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0),100.0);
        Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(0.2f,0.2f,1.0f);
        Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(+4.0f,-7.0f,-12.0f);
        DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight
                (light1Color,light1Direction);
        light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(light1);
        Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
        ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(ambientLightNode); 
        Color3f bgColor = new Color3f(0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        Background bg = new Background(bgColor);
        bg.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(bg);
        return objRoot;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph2(){
        objRoot2.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans2 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot2.addChild(objTrans2);
        sphere2 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans2 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans2.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans2.addChild(sphere2);
        objRoot2.addChild(objTrans2);
        return objRoot2;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph3(){
        objRoot3.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans3 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot3.addChild(objTrans3);
        sphere3 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans3 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans3.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans3.addChild(sphere3);
        objRoot3.addChild(objTrans3);
        return objRoot3;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph4(){
        objRoot4.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans4 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot4.addChild(objTrans4);
        sphere4 = new Sphere(0.45f);
        objTrans4 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans4.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans4.addChild(sphere4);
        objRoot4.addChild(objTrans4);
        return objRoot4;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph5(){
        objRoot5.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans5 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans5.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot5.addChild(objTrans5);
        sphere5 = new Sphere(0.45f);
        objTrans5 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans5.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans5.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans5.addChild(sphere5);
        objRoot5.addChild(objTrans5);
        return objRoot5;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph6(){
        objRoot6.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans6 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans6.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot6.addChild(objTrans6);
        sphere6 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans6 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans6.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans6.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans6.addChild(sphere6);
        objRoot6.addChild(objTrans6);
        return objRoot6;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph7(){
        objRoot7.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans7 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans7.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot7.addChild(objTrans7);
        sphere7 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans7 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans7.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans7.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans7.addChild(sphere7);
        objRoot7.addChild(objTrans7);
        return objRoot7;
    }

    public PAPITest(){
        setFocusable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(505,525);
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        c = new Canvas3D(config);
        Color color = new Color(0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        setBackground(color);
        setSize(600,600);
        Font font = new Font("Helvatica",Font.BOLD,18);
        scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + score);
        add("Center",c);
        c.addKeyListener(this);
        c.setSize(600,600);
        timer = new Timer(100,this);
        timer.start();
        scene = createSceneGraph();
        scene2 = createSceneGraph2();
        scene3 = createSceneGraph3();
        scene4 = createSceneGraph4();
        scene5 = createSceneGraph5();
        scene6 = createSceneGraph6();
        scene7 = createSceneGraph7();
        u = new SimpleUniverse(c);
        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        u.addBranchGraph(scene);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene2);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene3);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene4);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene5);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene6);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene7);
        rightX = 2.5f;
        right = 4.0f;
        float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -2.7f + -3.1f;
        float randomSpawn2 = (float) Math.random() * -5.7f + -15.1f;
        float randomSpawn3 = (float) Math.random() * 5.7f + 18.1f;
        leftX = randomSpawn;
        left = randomSpawn;
        rightX2 = randomSpawn3;
        leftX2 = randomSpawn2;
        rightDx = -.05f;
        leftDx = .05f;  
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd'|e.getKeyChar() == 'D'|e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT){
            xloc = xloc + .1f;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a'|e.getKeyChar() == 'A'|e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT){
            xloc = xloc - .1f;
        }
    }    

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        height += .1f * sign;
        if(Math.abs(height * 2) >= 1)
            sign = -1.0f * sign;
        height2 += .1f * sign2;
        if(Math.abs(height2 * 2) >= 1)
            sign2 = -1.0f * sign2;
        Vector3d vec;
        int thing = 1;
        int thing2 = 2;
        if(height < -.4f){
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,.8,1.0);
        }else{
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
          thing = 2;
        }
        trans.setScale(vec);
        trans.setTranslation(new Vector3f(xloc,height - .15f,0.0f));
        objTrans.setTransform(trans);
        if(height < -.10f){
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
          thing2 = 1;
        }
        if(height < -.4f){
          trans.setScale(new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0));
        }
        if(score >= 1000){
            rightDx = -.06f;
            leftDx = .06f; 
        }
        if(score >= 2000){
            rightDx = -.07f;
            leftDx = .07f; 
        }
        if(score >= 4000){
            rightDx = -.08f;
            leftDx = .08f; 
        }
        if(score >= 5000){
            rightDx = -.1f;
            leftDx = .1f; 
        }
        if(score >= 10000){
            rightDx = -.2f;
            leftDx = .2f; 
        }
        if(score >= 15000){
            rightDx = -.3f;
            leftDx = .3f; 
        }
        Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(rightX += rightDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector);
        objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector2 = new Vector3f(leftX += leftDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector2);
        objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector3 = new Vector3f(rightX2 += rightDx,-.4f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector3);
        objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector4 = new Vector3f(leftX2 += leftDx,-.4f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector4);
        objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector5 = new Vector3f(right += rightDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector5);
        objTrans6.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector6 = new Vector3f(left += leftDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector6);
        objTrans7.setTransform(trans);
        float leftXDistance = vector2.x - xloc - .22f;
        float xDistance = vector.x - xloc + .22f;
        float yDistance = -.7f - height;
        float xDistance2 = vector3.x - xloc - .05f;
        float yDistance2 = -.4f - height + .22f;
        float xDistance3 = vector5.x - xloc + .22f;
        float leftXDistance2 = vector4.x - xloc + .05f;
        float leftXDistance3 = vector6.x - xloc - .22f;
        double distance = Math.sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double distance2 = Math.sqrt((xDistance2 * xDistance2) + (yDistance2 * yDistance2));
        double distance3 = Math.sqrt((xDistance3 * xDistance3) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double leftDistance = Math.sqrt((leftXDistance * leftXDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double leftDistance2 = Math.sqrt((leftXDistance2 * leftXDistance2) + (yDistance2 * yDistance2));
        double leftDistance3 = Math.sqrt((leftXDistance3 * leftXDistance3) + (yDistance2 * yDistance2));
        if(distance < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 3.1f;
                rightX = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector);
                objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                score -= 100;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(distance3 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 3.1f;
                right = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector5);
                objTrans6.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                score -= 100;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(distance2 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing2 == 2){
                score += 200;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 4.1f + 20.9f;
                rightX2 = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector3);
                objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing2 == 1){
                score -= 200;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftDistance < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.7f;
                leftX = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector2);
                objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                score -= 100;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftDistance3 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.7f;
                left = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector6);
                objTrans7.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                score -= 100;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftDistance2 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing2 == 2){
                score += 200;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -3.1f + -17.9f;
                leftX2 = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector4);
                objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing2 == 1){
                score -= 200;
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        if(rightX < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            rightX = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector);
            objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(leftX > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            leftX = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector2);
            objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(right < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            right = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector);
            objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(left > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            left = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector2);
            objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(rightX2 < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            rightX2 = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector3);
            objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(leftX2 > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            leftX2 = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector4);
            objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(xloc > .8f){
            xloc = .8f;
        }
        if(xloc < -.8f){
            xloc = -.8f;
        }
        sumScore = score;
        if(!isAlive){
            setBackground(Color.black);
            remove(scoreLabel);
            remove(c);
            setSize(600,600);
            setVisible(true);
            Font font = new Font("Helvatica",Font.BOLD,24);
            if(sumScore < 0){
                sumScore = 0;
            }
            JLabel label = new JLabel("                             Your Score: " + sumScore);           
            label.setFont(font);
            add(label);
            setVisible(true);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your game normally get started? For example, what code is executed when you press "Start" on the menuscreen?

Comment: Hard to tell without the rest of your code, but you problably need to create a new papi object

Comment: We need a lot more context.  I am guessing, although I can't be sure, that this code occurs in a `JPanel` or `JFrame`, so the `add` and `remove` calls will only remove it from the display - it won't restart your game.  What is `papi`?  That looks like the place where this needs to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still difficult to tell, but it appears that these are the crucial lines:

```
    papi = new PAPITest();
    papig = new PAPIGame();
```

These two together seem to manage the state of your game, so if you re-create them, you should start your game over.  For example:

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && papi.isAlive() != true){ 
    remove(papi);
    papi = new PAPITest();
    papig = new PAPIGame();
    papi.setSize(600,600);
    add(papi);
    setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}
```